# Defining variable length structs and casting to them

Tags: d

In C, you sometimes see something like:

```
struct foobar
{
    int size;
    int data[1];
};
```

where the `data` member doesn't really have just one element; rather it's meant to be variable length.
If you do something like that in D, is it going to let you, for example, read `myfoobar.data[4]`?
I know D has variable length arrays, e.g. `int[] myvarlenintarray;`, but what if you're trying to interface with some code that already puts out a data structure in memory like the one above, and possibly much more complex than that?  Let's say it's in the first portion of `int[3000] buffer;`.  Is there an easy way to cast it to a usable struct without moving it in memory?  If not, is there an easy way to get the data into a similar struct without having to manually parse out each member of the struct?

edit:

I think I need to give a practical example so you see where I'm coming from.

```
import std.c.windows.windows;
import std.utf;
import std.stdio;

public struct REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER
{
  ULONG  ReparseTag;
  USHORT ReparseDataLength;
  USHORT Reserved;
  union
  {
    struct SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer
    {
      USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
      USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
      USHORT PrintNameOffset;
      USHORT PrintNameLength;
      ULONG Flags;
      WCHAR[1] PathBuffer;
    }
    SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer mySymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
    struct MountPointReparseBuffer
    {
      USHORT SubstituteNameOffset;
      USHORT SubstituteNameLength;
      USHORT PrintNameOffset;
      USHORT PrintNameLength;
      WCHAR[1] PathBuffer;
    }
    MountPointReparseBuffer myMountPointReparseBuffer;
    struct GenericReparseBuffer
    {
        UCHAR[1] DataBuffer;
    }
    GenericReparseBuffer myGenericReparseBuffer;
  }
}
alias REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* PREPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;
enum MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 16*1024;

// Values for 'ReparseTag' member of REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER:
enum : DWORD {
    IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK = 0xA000000C,
    IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT = 0xA0000003 // which also defines a Junction Point
}
enum DWORD FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT = 0x000900a8;
enum FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT = 0x00200000;

public extern(Windows) BOOL function(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID, DWORD, LPVOID, DWORD, LPVOID, OVERLAPPED*) DeviceIoControl;

void main()
{
    DeviceIoControl = cast(BOOL function(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID, DWORD, LPVOID, DWORD, LPVOID, OVERLAPPED*))GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll"), "DeviceIoControl");
    auto RPHandle = CreateFileW((r"J:\Documents and Settings").toUTF16z(), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, null, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT + FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, null);
    if (RPHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFileW failed with error code %d.", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    BYTE[MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE] reparsebuffer;
    uint reparsedatasize;
    auto getreparsepointresult = DeviceIoControl(RPHandle, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, null, 0, cast(void*) reparsebuffer.ptr, MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE, &reparsedatasize, null);
    if (getreparsepointresult == 0)
    {
        printf("DeviceIoControl with FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT failed with error code %d.", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    // Now what?
    // If I do this:
    auto ReparseDataPtr = cast(REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*) reparsebuffer.ptr;
    printf("%d == %d\n", reparsebuffer.ptr, ReparseDataPtr); // Alright, data hasn't been copied.
    // But what good is a pointer?  Can I use a pointer to a struct to access one of its members apart from dereferencing?
    printf("%d == %d\n", &reparsebuffer[0], &(*ReparseDataPtr)); // Here, I dereference ReparseDataPtr, but nothing moves.
    printf("%d == %d\n", &reparsebuffer[0], &((*ReparseDataPtr).ReparseTag)); // Same here, so I can access members in a roundabout way.
    printf("%d == %d\n", &reparsebuffer[0], &(ReparseDataPtr.ReparseTag)); // And thanks to Jim's comment, here's a less roundabout way.
    auto ReparseData = *ReparseDataPtr; // But if I assign a name to the dereferenced ReparseDataPtr, 
    printf("%d != %d\n", &reparsebuffer[0], &(ReparseData.ReparseTag)); // the data is copied to a new location, leaving most of PathBuffer behind.
    REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER ReparseDataFn() {return *ReparseDataPtr;} // Similarly, this way
    printf("%d != %d\n", &reparsebuffer[0], &(ReparseDataFn().ReparseTag)); // copies stuff to a new location.

}
```

Firstly, I don't understand why it's different for the case in which I don't give `*ReparseDataPtr` a name.

Secondly, is there no way to have a symbol whose type is REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER and whose data is located at reparsebuffer.ptr?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried doing the exact same thing in D as in C?

```
struct foobar { int size; int data[1]; };
```

It works... just use `data.ptr` instead of `data` to access the elements, because otherwise it will perform bounds checking with a length of 1.

Comment: at first, I did something like `foobar myfoobar = *cast(foobar*) &buffer;`, but `myfoobar` got moved instead of just overlapping `buffer`.  The first part of the struct was fine, but then garbage because I guess it only moved it like it contained an array of length one, as I'd defined `foobar`.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you dereference something whose size you don't know? Do you do that in C?

Comment: Don't assume I know what I'm doing; I have __very little__ experience in either C or D.  I'm working on my first useful D program right now, and I've never written a useful C program - I just know a little about it from its sheer ubiquity and similarity to some other languages.  In short, I want to treat the memory at `&buffer` as though it contained a `foobar`.  I'm thinking that in C, I could do something like `foobar* myfoobarptr = &buffer;`, and then access members using `myfoobarptr->size`, for example.  That avoids the dereferencing somewhat, but D doesn't have `->` AFAIK.

Comment: @WootenAround Certainly D has `->` ... it just spells it `.` -- there's never any ambiguity between the two.

Comment: ^^ That makes sense, thanks!  I didn't realize I could do that.

Comment: @Downvoter It's quite current to do that in C when reading data whose size is runtime dependent. Think of a TCP packet for example: you can't possibly know the size at compile time. Doing that trick you can have in the struct the length of data and a pointer to the data itself. It's very useful when well used.

Answer (score 1):

You could access it via a helper method:

```
struct foobar
{
 public:
  int[] Data() { return data.ptr[0..size]; }

 private:
  int size;
  int data[1];
}
```

You might also want to put int a static `foreach` over the members of `foobar` that uses `static assert` to make sure that the offset of each is less than the offset of `data`.

Comment: A method (or a `@property`) for getting the variable-length member is a good idea, but how do I get `&myfoobar == &buffer`?

Comment: @WootenAround: IIRC you can do an explicit cast from `void*` (or any pointer for that matter) to `foobar*` just as  you would in C. I don't know of any cases where D's pointer semantics differ from C's (all the fun stuff C++ adds (mostly from multiple inheritances) is relegated to class references which aren't technically pointers in D).